# How to get iTunes connect Team ID and Team name?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I'm writing down an `Appfile` for **`fastlane`**, my problem is I already have the `team_name` and `team_id` in Apple Dev Center but I can't get the `iTunes Connect ID`/**`itc_team_id`**. I'm working with different team. How do I get it? Any guide would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can get it directly from Spaceship (See the "Login" section) (https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/iTunesConnect.md)

Basically just type the following in a shell:

```
$ irb
irb> require "spaceship"
irb> Spaceship::Tunes.login("iTunesConnect_username", "iTunesConnect_password")
irb> Spaceship::Tunes.select_team
```

You'll be presented with a list of teams your account belongs to, along with the numerical representation for that team.

Answer (score 184):

If you are not on your Mac, you can get it through the iTunes connect website.

- Login to App Store Connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)
- Get output (JSON) from (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/user/detail)
- You can now get your iTunes Connect ids from the `associatedAccounts` array with the different `contentProvider` objects - the entry named `contentProviderId` reflects the iTunes Connect id, lookup for the `name` value to pick the correct one

Source: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/4301#issuecomment-253461017

Comment: Works 2021. Should only rename itunes store connect to appstore connect so you stay up to date with Apple's naming.

Comment: That's the best answer. Also works in 2021. Especially if you have 2fa enabled. Probably fastlane and apple will make it easier in the future.

Comment: Best answer. THANKS.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of trying to get it manually, just run *fastlane* without specifying the team ID. Once the selection is required, *fastlane* will list all the available iTunes Connect teams and their IDs, and you can then store this number.

Comment: I've done that before and actually saw the `itc_team_id` for different teams but I'm building a NodeJS application where I run a `shell` command `fastlane` there. Basically, it is an automation build process where I don't need to answer/select the `itc_team_id` by just overwritting the Appfile and place the `itc_team_id` there. By the way, nice software you have.

Comment: If you are using fastlane deliver for example, do "fastlane deliver -u <account_user_name>" and it will show the list of team ids for iTunes Connect

Comment: Is there any way to get the App Store Connect ID (not team id) without going through fastlane? I have an operations team that is not going to be running a cli to determine build parameters. I've scoured the internet for an answer to this.. no avail. Maybe you can shed some light @KrauseFx ?

Answer (score 10):

## Easiest way

**`fastlane produce`**

if you are in multiple teams it will show

```
[16:36:43]: Your Apple ID Username: youremail@icloud.com
Available session is not valid any more. Continuing with normal login.
Multiple teams found on the Developer Portal, please enter the number of the team you want to use: 
1) 89******8K "B******d Incorporated" (Company/Organization)
2) B8******ZP "Sultanmyrza Kasymbekov" (Individual)
```

you should choose one after it will as you again

```
[16:38:19]: [DevCenter] App 'co.brainfood.brainfood' already exists, nothing to do on the Dev Center
Available session is not valid any more. Continuing with normal login.
Multiple App Store Connect teams found, please enter the number of the team you want to use: 
Note: to automatically choose the team, provide either the App Store Connect Team ID, or the Team Name in your fastlane/Appfile:
Alternatively you can pass the team name or team ID using the `FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID` or `FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_NAME` environment variable

  itc_team_id "1******12"

or

  itc_team_name "B******d Incorporated"

1) "B******d Incorporated" (1*******2)
2) "Sultanmyrza Kasymbekov" (1******7)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest way to get it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Add below lane code to your fastlane `Fastfile` and run `fastlane getTeamNames`

```
 lane :getTeamNames do
  require "spaceship" 
  clientTunes = Spaceship::Tunes.login("{appleID}", "{applePassword}")
  client = Spaceship::Portal.login("{appleID}", "{applePassword}")

  strClientTunes = "" 
  clientTunes.teams.each do |team|
      UI.message "#{team['contentProvider']['name']} (#{team['contentProvider']['contentProviderId']})"
      strClientTunes << "#{team['contentProvider']['name']} (#{team['contentProvider']['contentProviderId']})||"
  end 
  File.write('ItunesTeamNames', strClientTunes[0..-3])

  strDevPortal = "" 
  client.teams.each do |team|
      UI.message "#{team['name']} (#{team['teamId']})"
      strDevPortal << "#{team['name']} (#{team['teamId']})||"
  end
  File.write('DevTeamNames', strDevPortal[0..-3])

end
```

Get iTunes connect Team ID and Team name from `ItunesTeamNames` and `DevTeamNames` files in fastlane folder

Note:- Replace `{appleID}` and `{applePassword}` with your apple id and password

Answer (score 5):

I'm using fastlane, managing multiple accounts with one login.

- To get all **dev_team_id**s (Developer Portal Team ID), I run the following command:

```
    fastlane match
```

- To get all **c_team_id**s (App Store Connect Team ID), I run the following command:

```
    fastlane deliver
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the Spaceship playground. It is easy to use and you don't need any prior project setup. If you are working on a lot of teams and need to get the itc_team_id on a regular basis, you can leave the Playground running.

From shell

```
fastlane spaceship
[✔]  
[16:37:57]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
Username: you@youremail.com
Logging into to App Store Connect (you@youremail.com)...
Successfully logged in to App Store Connect

Logging into the Developer Portal (you@youremail.com)...
Successfully logged in to the Developer Portal

---------------------------------------
| Welcome to the spaceship playground |
---------------------------------------

Enter docs to open up the documentation
Enter exit to exit the spaceship playground
Enter _ to access the return value of the last executed command

Just enter the commands and confirm with Enter
[1] pry(#<Spaceship::Playground>)> Spaceship::Tunes.select_team
```

Note the select_team call above. It will show you the list of the teams you are on along with the itc_team_id