# Fastlane failing with error "Cannot obtain the content provider public id. Please specify a provider short name using the -asc_provider option."

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, fastlane

I created an iOS test flight build using Fastlane, and I got this strange error, not sure why because it was working fine yesterday and now without any change in Fastlane configuration it gives me an error while uploading the build to the Apple App store.

errors wordings are as below

```
[21:50:01]: Transporter transfer failed.
[21:50:01]: 
[21:50:01]: Cannot obtain the content provider public id. Please specify a provider short name using the -asc_provider option.

[21:50:02]: Cannot obtain the content provider public id. Please specify a provider short name using the -asc_provider option.
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: Cannot obtain the content provider public id. Please specify a provider short name using the -asc_provider option.
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

[21:50:02]: Error uploading ipa file: 


[21:50:02]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error uploading ipa file:
```

Refer below logs
[image]

Comment: Run fastlane with `--verbose` and see if the issue is more clear from detailed logs

Comment: oh, and also: "If you are on multiple App Store Connect teams, iTunes Transporter may need a provider short name to know where to upload your binary. pilot will try to use the long name of the selected team to detect the provider short name. To override the detected value with an explicit one, use the itc_provider option." (source: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/)

Comment: Don't show pictures of code if you can help it. I'm pretty sure you can copy that stuff out of the fastlane log and paste it into the question _as code text_.

Comment: [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why you should use text instead of images of text. Flag this and the other image-related comment as "no longer needed" after you have edited.

Answer (score 16):

For those who are suffering with this on Azure Devops's `AppStoreRelease` task. Using @user20291554 solution it can be fixed as follows

```yaml
 - job: ios
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-latest
    variables:
      DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: "-asc_provider <your team ID or short name if different>"
    steps:
      ...
      - task: AppStoreRelease@1
        inputs:
      ...
```

Comment: can we mention `DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS ` in variable group `variables:
    - group: App Variables`

Comment: @Sagar Yes, it worked for me also in variables group. Name: "DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS" . Value: "-asc_provider 12345" where 12345 is your team id.

Comment: @K232 can I add this on Azure lib. variable group instead of `.YML` file. I received `The username xyz.com is not a member of the provider 12345`

Comment: For those that are on the old 'classic' release pipelines, add the variable under the 'variables' tab and leave out the double quotes around the value - worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Please add the `itc_provider` along with the `apple_id` on the below line of code.

```rb
upload_to_testflight(
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
    apple_id: "APPLE_ID",
    itc_provider:"ID" #example: W4A0P2BYMN
)
```

If you are on multiple App Store Connect teams, deliver needs a provider short name to know where to upload your binary. deliver will try to use the **long name** of the selected team to detect the provider **short name**. To override the detected value with an explicit one, use the **itc_provider** option.

- [Fastlane reference doc for itc_provider](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/)
- [Stackoverflow: To get provider short name(itc_provider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960644/how-to-get-itunes-connect-team-id-and-team-name)
- [Fastlane Github: related ticket](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10796#issuecomment-352952685)

Comment: In the azure pipeline where we can add the id's

Answer (score 7):

I had the same.

This [comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20756#issuecomment-1283773210) from github helped me.

> Add ENV variable to your deployment (or local machine , or Fastfile
> directly) With DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS we
> can add the "missing" -asc_provider variable.
>
> ENV["DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS"] =
> "-asc_provider YourShortName" Just deployed and it works for those who
> can't wait.

Answer (score 7):

For me adding the environment variable works perfectly:

```
ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD: true
```

For my case, here is an example of Azure DevOps pipelines:

```yaml
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
    env:
        ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD: true
    ...
```

Source [Fastlane GitHub issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20756)

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved it!

```
      deliver(
        app_identifier: '{{YOUR_APP_ID}}',
        submit_for_review: false,
        skip_screenshots: true,
        force: true,
        itc_provider: "{{YOUR_TEAM_ID}}" // <- added!
      )
```

Comment: in the azure pipeline where we can mention these id's

Answer (score 6):

To get itc_provider run command
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m provider -u 'appleid@xxx.xx' -p 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -account_type itunes_connect -v off

where
appleid@xxx.xx your appleid
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx - password for your app

How to generate an app-specific password

- Sign in to appleid.apple.com.
- In the Sign-In and Security section, select App-Specific Passwords.
- Select Generate an app-specific password or select the Add button Blue plus sign icon., then follow the steps on your screen.
- Enter or paste the app-specific password into the password field of the app.

[image]

Comment: What do I do if the itms folder does not exist? (Running Xcode 14.)

Comment: You can download it from https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html

Answer (score 1):

Im using the `fastlane deliver` to upload my apps

The solution for me was:
Add new tag/flag for command `fastlane deliver`
Example:  `fastlane deliver --username xxx@xxx.com`....

And new tag added was `--itc-provider my_team_id`

You can found your team_id here: [page](https://developer.apple.com/account/)

So, the command at the end was:
`fastlane deliver  --verbose --ipa xxx --username xxx  --app_identifier xxx --itc_provider team_id`

xxx => corresponds about your project
team_id => corresponds about Team ID, that you can get on page above